# Importing Module(PyCogent) with Python

Tags: python, windows, numpy, module

I'm having trouble installing the Pycogent 1.5.3 module on Python.

1. I Downloaded it(PyCogent-1.5.3.tgz) and then unzipped it with 7-zip.
2. I then open the cmd(windows), and go to the Pycogent directory. Then I try to set it up with "python setup.py install"
3. First error i had to deal with, was the need to setup Numpy version 1.3 or greater. Done. Now Numpy is shown on the python site packages.
4. Now the error i get when trying to setup Pycogent is:

   ```
   running install
   running build
   running build_py
   running build_ext
   building 'cogent.align._compare' extension
   error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
   ```

I installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and still get this error. Any ideas?
Could it be that it's not possible to import this module on windows?
On this website it says something about problems on gz file compression
http://pycogent.org/install.html

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which python version do you have? 64 bits versions require full version of MSVC, 3.3 requires 2010, but 3.2 and lower need 2008. http://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html#windows

Comment: I've got Python 2.7. Visual studio 2008 and 2013 couldnt be installed on my computer(for certain requirements reasons)

Comment: Anyways, my python is the 32 bit version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCogent does not work on windows unless you have a Linux virtual machine installed.

Taken from Pycogent's installation guide ([here](http://pycogent.org/install.html)):

[image]

Let me know if you need help installing the QIIME virtual box if you want to really use PyCogent with Windows.

Comment: Thanks, indeed I had to use another Virtual Machine.